# OpenGL - How do I compare pixel values from separate textures with the same location

Tags: opengl

I was wondering what is the best way to go about comparing a pixel that 
is currently being rendered (and accessed using a fragment shader) to a
pixel with the same location in a previously stored unbound texture (both
textures are the same size)?

Comment: So you are saying that you have captured the framebuffer in an earlier frame, and you want to compare two pixels at the same locations on the captured framebuffer, and the current framebuffer?

Comment: there is no such thing as a "same location" for a texel in a generic texture (for starter, they might have different sizes, have a different format...) and the fragmen. How about you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok. So I have a 640x480 RGBA texture stored after performing an edge detection shader on a video frame. I also have a wireframe model of an object with hidden lines removed that I am trying to detect in the video frame. I am trying to compare pixels in the wireframe model to give me a count of how many of these pixels correspond to video frame edges using another pixel shader. This pixel count will then give me a likelihood of how well that models pose fits in the current video frame. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the question is more clear, it's possible to give an answer.

The main issue is that the framebuffer contents and the fragment parameters (position) are not available in the fragment shader. Indeed, you can't execute the "compare" operation while rendering.

You have to render the model in a texture (search for render to texture, using frame buffer objects), and then run a fragment shader (maybe using GL_texture_rectangle) on a otho view with a viewport of the same size of the texture.

The fragment shader shall have two textures as input: the first texture (containing detected edges) and the texture-rendered wireframe model. Then, it's easy to perform complex computation in the fragment shader once you can access to each textel of both textures.

Comment: Is it possible to do this by projecting the texture onto the model using projective texture mapping?

Comment: I cannot naswer: all depends on the the specific texturing paramateres (values, coords...).

I would suggest for your task (comparing pixels) the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation: i've used to search volumes in 3d images. THe main advantage is that it search for pixel variations, instead of pixel values (indeed is pixel intesity independent).